# Extjs - selecting a form inside a rowexpander

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have a form on a panel inside a rowexpnader, and I want to select it.
this is how I tried and nothing happend:

```
Ext.getCmp("tabs").getActiveTab().down('grid').down('panel').form('fotm-id').getForm()
Ext.getCmp("tabs").getActiveTab().down('grid').down('panel').form('#fotm-id').getForm()
Ext.getCmp("tabs").getActiveTab().down('grid').down().form('fotm-id').getForm()
```

I dont remember now, but I tried more variations but it is not working at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by listening the event, on that event get the panel reference and apply down to get the form. Please refer sample example below

```
expand( p, eOpts ){

  var formRef = p.down('fotm-id').getForm()

}
```